# Неправильно работает условие

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, я новичок в С++ и начал изучение с видеоуроков (просьбы по этому поводу не говорите, ибо только базовое смотрю по урокам, дальше найду литературу). Пробую написать калькулятор, который будет после операций выдавать, были ли переменные негативными или нет. Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    const int maxCnt = 10;
    float a[maxCnt], b[maxCnt];
    char op[maxCnt]; //operator
    float res; //resultl
    int cnt = 0;
    char answer = 'y'; //answer

    while( (answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y') && cnt < maxCnt)
    {
        cout << "Enter expression: ";
        cin >>  a[cnt] >> op[cnt] >> b[cnt];
        switch (op[cnt])
        {
            case '+':
                res = a[cnt]+b[cnt];
                break;

            case '-':
                res = a[cnt]-b[cnt];
                break;

            case '*':
                res = a[cnt]*b[cnt];
                break;

            case '/':
                res = a[cnt]/b[cnt];
                if (b == 0) {
                    cout << "You can't use 0" << endl;
                    system( "pause" );
                    return 0;
                }
                break;

            default: 
                cout << "Bad operator" << endl;
                cout << "Continue? [y/n] ";
                cin >> answer;
                if(answer == 'y'|| answer == 'Y')
                    continue;   
                if(answer == 'n'|| answer == 'N')
                    return 0;
        }

        cout << "Result: " << res << endl;

        cout << "Continue? [y/n] ";
        cin >> answer;

        cnt++;

        if(cnt == maxCnt)
        {
            system( "pause");
            break;          
        }

    }

    bool Negative = false;

    int Del = 0;
    int Umn = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<cnt; i++)
    {

        if(a[i]<0 || b[i]<0)
            Negative = true;
        if(a[i]>=0 && b[i]>=0)
            Negative = false;

        if(op[i]=='*')
            Umn++;
        else if(op[i]=='/')
            Del++;
    }


    if(Negative = false)
        cout << "Were not Negative"<<endl;
    else if(Negative=true)
        cout << "Were negative"<<endl;

    system ("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

И когда я ввожу положительные значения, он всё равно выводит Were Negative. Подскажите, что делаю не так? Может, не туда вставляю?

Comment: 1)
``   case '/':
        res = a[cnt]/b[cnt];
        if (b == 0){
            cout << "You can't use 0" << endl;
            system( "pause" );
            return 0;``
Вы делите на ``b[cnt]`` без проверки на 0. Проверка ``b == 0`` в данном случае бессмысленна.

2) ``return`` в ``case``, лучше этого избегать.

Comment: 1) А как тогда сделать, чтоб шла проверка на ноль?
2) спасибо, уже и сам понял, что глупо

Comment: Если числа целые, то просто ``if (b[cnt] == 0)``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Замените
`if(Negative = false)`

на
`if(Negative == false)`

аналогично для `true`

В данном случае Вы не проверяете на равенство, а выполняете присваивание переменной `Negative` значения `false`. Это известная проблема синтаксиса С++, потому есть рекомендация писать `if (false == Negative)`. В этом случае, если Вы вдруг ошибетесь и поставите "=", компилятор выдаст сообщение о синтаксической ошибке.

Comment: спасибо, действительно с этим пока проблемы

Comment: А что за компилятор? Разве он не выдаёт предупреждение о присваивании в пределах условного выражения?

Comment: MSVC++ 2010 Express. Нет, ничего не выдавал у меня

Comment: @GLmonster, а какие компиляторы выдают такие предупреждения ?

Comment: >какие компиляторы выдают такие предупреждения ?

 У меня Visual C++ 2010 выдаёт. Наверное потому, что я делаю четвёртый уровень предупреждений, а у остальных по умолчанию третий стоит.